# Trouble understanding how to configure Eclipse Paho C client in Linux

Tags: c, compilation, cmake, mqtt, paho

I am trying to get up and running with MQTT paho, as I am developing an application that is going to be required to transmit via MQTT.

Right now I am just trying to get off the ground by getting the sample code provided by the Paho project running.

I am cloning the repository using the command: 
`git clone https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c.git`

This the part that I am most unsure about, what flags are need for the code located in `/src` to be compiled and what do I have to do with Cmake/make files for my code to be able to compile and run correcty?

For reference I was originally trying to get the asynchronous publish client code running that was provided at `http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/Cclient/pubasync.html`

Any help on this would be appreciated as I am decently lost on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

The example you shared is quite simple, not require any other configs.
Follow the steps if you haven't installed paho C client yet :

```
1. git clone https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c.git
2. cd paho.mqtt.c.git
3. make
4. sudo make install
```

Please notice that you may need to have libssl-dev. For more info check [this page](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c).

You can compile this example by the command below:

```
gcc example.c -lpaho-mqtt3c
```

Still, if you need to do some build config, your choices are :

```
cmake -GNinja -DPAHO_WITH_SSL=TRUE -DPAHO_BUILD_DOCUMENTATION=TRUE -DPAHO_BUILD_SAMPLES=TRUE ~/git/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.c
```